# Apache Kafka: consumer state

Tags: messaging, asynchronous, apache-kafka

I read the documentation on the Kafka website but after trying to implement a complete minimal example ( producer --> kafka --> consumer) it's not very clear to me how the "consumer state", the offset needs to be handled.

Some info

1. I'm using the HighLevel API (Java)
2. My consumer is a simple class with a Main, basically the same that can be found on the "quickstart" Kafka page
3. I'm using Zookeeper
4. I'm using a single broker

Now, the documentation says that the HighLevel API consumer stores its state using zookeeper so I would expect the offset and therefore the state of the consumer would be maintained between

- Kafka broker restarts
- Consumer restarts

But unfortunately it doesn't: each time I restart the broker or the consumer, all messages are re-delivered.
Now, probably these are stupid questions but

1. **In case of Kafka restart**: I understood that is up to the consumer to keep its state so probably when the broker (re)starts up redeliver all (!) messages and the consumer decides what to consume...is that right? If so, what happens if I have 10.0000.0000 of messages?
2. **In case of JVM consumer restart**: if the state is kept on Zookeeper why are the messages re-delivered? Is it possibile that the new JVM has a different consumer "identity"? And in this case, how can I bind the previous identity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I have been a bad reader...it's all in the configuration page. Specifically both of my questions were solved by setting a flag "autooffset.reset" which defaults to "smallest" and therefore causes the effects described.

Now, with "largest" as value, things are working as expected, both in case of consumer and broker restart, because the offset is always the largest.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, consumer is responsible for keeping its state, and Java high-level Consumer saves its state in zookeeper.

Most likely you didn't specify `groupId` configuration property. In that situation kafka generates random `groupId`.

It's also possible that you turned off `autocommit.enable` configuration property.

Full reference of Kafka configuration might be found on this page:  http://kafka.apache.org/configuration.html under **"Important configuration properties for the high-level consumer"** title.

Answer (score 4):

to answer the original question: using groupId helps avoid the "re-consuming all messages from the beginning of time" situation

if you change the groupId you'll get all messages from the moment the queue was created (or since the last data purge based on kafka logs retention policy)

don't confuse this with kafka-console-consumer "--from-beginning" flag (which sets  auto.offset.reset option)  which is there to choose between options 1 and 2 below:

1) consume new messages from the moment the last message was consumed (NOT from the beginning of time when kafka queue was originally created):

*props.put("auto.offset.reset","smallest");*

2) consume new messages from the moment subscriber JVM is started (in this case you risk missing messages put on the queue while subscriber was down and not listening to the queue):

*props.put("auto.offset.reset","largest");*

---

*side note: below is only tangentially related to the original question*

for a more advanced use case  - if you're trying to programatically set consumer offset to replay messages starting from certain time -  it would require using SimpleConsumer API as shown in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example in order to find the smallest offset to replay from the right broker/partition. Which is essentially replacing zookeeper with our own FindLeader logic. very tricky.

for this use case (ad-hoc replay of messages starting from certain user-specified time) we decided to store local cache of the messages and manage offsets locally instead of using kafka offset management api (which would require reimplementing a good chunk of zookeeper functionality with SimpleConsumer).

I.e. treat kafka as a "postman", once the message is delivered it goes to local mailbox and in case we need to go back to a certain offset in the past and, say, replay the messages (that have been already consumed) e.g. in case of consumer app error, we don't go back to the "post office" (kafka brokers) to figure out the correct delivery ordering, but manage it **locally**.

*end of side note*

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you manage offsets locally instead of from Kafka? Like how you determine and calculate the offsets for each message sent to then be consumed.

Comment: once consumed - add current timestamp as msg id, and store message as binary blob  (it is sent in avro format and we dont deserialize it at this point)  in hsql (with persistence to disk) , or you can use apache phoenix and archive it there in binary format with two columns ID (timestamp), Message(VARBINARY)

Comment: But how does that relate to message offset? The Kafka offset value isn't a timestamp or binary encoding of the message or hash of either is it? I'm still new to Kafka, so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: it doesn't, we don't care about kafka offset. we replace it with our own "offset" in a form of local timestamp when message is received and then use it for indexing the messages in local archive db which is periodically purged. if we need to replay the sequence of messages received within a certain (recent) time range it does the job. We read the messages from the db and send to destination (in the same order they were received originally from kafka).

Comment: to clarify - my comments above are for the use case of "ad-hoc replay of messages starting from certain user-specified time", which is different from the original question related to default kafka operation, I updated my answer to reflect this.